# In a Comment Archive Log – How to find Comments where User Name 1 at Latest Log is Equal to User Name 1 or User Name 2 at an Earlier Log?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in a factory that makes components for Trucks. At this factory, we manufacture these components in Batches on various machines. The Manufacturing steps of the components on the Machines are recorded in a Relational Database. Sometimes, issues occur during the Manufacture of these components, and we have to Log a Comment. This Data is then fed into a Table called CO_COMMENT_TEXT_LG.

Here is what a section of the table looks like:

| COMMENT_ID | TIMESTAMP | STATUS | USER_NAME_1 | USER_NAME_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COM_006273 | 13-FEB-22 13:56 | CLOSED | John Doe | NULL |
| COM_006273 | 13-FEB-22 08:45 | OPEN | Paul Jacobs | John Doe |
| COM_005091 | 11-FEB-22 16:53 | CLOSED | Mark Clarke | NULL |
| COM_005091 | 11-FEB-22 09:02 | OPEN | Paul Jacobs | John Doe |

Opening a Comment requires 2 Distinct User Names.
The Comment has to be Closed later and this requires just 1 User Name.
(Closing User Name always appears under USER_NAME_1 Column)
Also this may not be relevant, but Comments cannot be deleted or reopened.

A rule is that you can only Close an Exception – if you have not raised it.
However, the rule is often broken.

In the Example Data Above:

•   COM_006273 – the Rule was Broken. Joe Doe Closed the Comment but he was also an Opening User Name.

•   COM_005091 – the Rule was not Broken. Mark Clarke Closed the Comment but he was not an Opening User Name.

My Question is how do I write an SQL Query to gives me COMMENT_IDs where the Rule was Broken?
(So the Answer would be COM_006273 in this Case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing and compare adjacent open and closed rows:

```sql
SELECT comment_id
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY comment_id
         ORDER BY timestamp
         PATTERN (open invalid_closed)
         DEFINE
           open           AS  status = 'OPEN',
           invalid_closed AS  status = 'CLOSED'
                          AND user_name_1 IN (open.user_name_1, open.user_name_2)
       )
```

In earlier versions you could use a self-join:

```sql
SELECT o.comment_id
FROM   table_name o
       INNER JOIN table_name ic
       ON     o.comment_id =  ic.comment_id
          AND o.timestamp  <= ic.timestamp 
          AND ic.user_name_1 IN (o.user_name_1, o.user_name_2)
WHERE  o.status  = 'OPEN'
AND    ic.status = 'CLOSED';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COMMENT_ID, TIMESTAMP, STATUS, USER_NAME_1, USER_NAME_2) AS
SELECT 'COM_006273', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-13 13:56:00', 'CLOSED', 'John Doe',    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'COM_006273', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-13 08:45:00', 'OPEN',   'Paul Jacobs', 'John Doe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'COM_005091', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 16:53:00', 'CLOSED', 'Mark Clarke', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'COM_005091', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 09:02:00', 'OPEN',   'Paul Jacobs', 'John Doe' FROM DUAL;
```

Which both output:

| COMMENT_ID |
| --- |
| COM_006273 |

---

If you want more information, you could `UNPIVOT` the user-names and then `PIVOT` the timestamps and filter:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       UNPIVOT (
         user_name FOR type IN (
           user_name_1 AS 1,
           user_name_2 AS 2
         )
       )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(timestamp)
         FOR (status, type) IN (
           ('OPEN', 1) AS ts_o1,
           ('OPEN', 2) AS ts_o2,
           ('CLOSED', 1) AS ts_c1
         )
       )
WHERE  ts_o1 < ts_c1
OR     ts_o2 < ts_c1;
```

Which outputs:

| COMMENT_ID | USER_NAME | TS_O1 | TS_O2 | TS_C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COM_006273 | John Doe | *null* | 2022-02-13 08:45:00.000000000 | 2022-02-13 13:56:00.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i0gWYPE1)

Comment: Thank You!
It was the Self Join that I got working in the end. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are just OPEN and CLOSED statuses  (with closing user 2 Is Null) you can use simple Group by with HAVING clause like below - it's simple, readable and maintainable:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (COMMENT_ID,    TIME_STAMP, STATUS, USER_NAME_1,    USER_NAME_2) AS
        ( Select 'COM_006273',  To_Date('2022-02-13 13:56',  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CLOSED', 'John Doe', NULL From Dual Union All
          Select 'COM_006273',  To_Date('2022-02-13 08:45',  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'OPEN', 'Paul Jacobs',  'John Doe' From Dual Union All
          Select 'COM_005091',  To_Date('2022-02-11 16:53',  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CLOSED',   'Mark Clarke',  NULL From Dual Union All
          Select 'COM_005091',  To_Date('2022-02-11 09:02',  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'OPEN', 'Paul Jacobs',  'John Doe' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--       S Q L :
Select    COMMENT_ID
From      tbl
Group By  COMMENT_ID
Having    Count(Distinct Coalesce(USER_NAME_2, USER_NAME_1)) = 1 And -- same (1) user for OPEN and CLOSED
          Count(*) = 2  -- both rows exist
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :
COMMENT_ID
----------
COM_006273   */
```

To see complete data involved in broken rule just put the above SQL as a condition (filter) in WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      tbl
WHERE     COMMENT_ID IN( Select    COMMENT_ID
                         From         tbl
                         Group By  COMMENT_ID
                         Having    Count(Distinct Coalesce(USER_NAME_2, USER_NAME_1)) = 1 And
                                   Count(*) = 2
                        )
/*      R e s u l t :
COMMENT_ID TIME_STA STATUS USER_NAME_1 USER_NAM
---------- -------- ------ ----------- --------
COM_006273 13.02.22 OPEN   Paul Jacobs John Doe
COM_006273 13.02.22 CLOSED John Doe              */
```

And if you want to be more descriptive use conditional aggregation, group by and having clause:

```sql
SELECT    COMMENT_ID, 
          Max(Case When STATUS = 'OPEN' Then USER_NAME_1 || ' & ' || USER_NAME_2 End) "OPENED_BY", 
          Max(Case When STATUS = 'OPEN' Then To_Char(TIME_STAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') End) "OPENED_AT", 
          Max(Case When STATUS = 'CLOSED' Then USER_NAME_1 End) "CLOSED_BY", 
          Max(Case When STATUS = 'CLOSED' Then To_Char(TIME_STAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') End) "CLOSED_AT"
FROM      tbl
GROUP BY  COMMENT_ID
HAVING    Count(Distinct Coalesce(USER_NAME_2, USER_NAME_1)) = 1 And
          Count(*) = 2
/*
COMMENT_ID OPENED_BY              OPENED_AT        CLOSED_BY   CLOSED_AT       
---------- ---------------------- ---------------- ----------- ----------------
COM_006273 Paul Jacobs & John Doe 2022-02-13 08:45 John Doe    2022-02-13 13:56  */
```